# Vlookup within an IfError statement tying two columns to one result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am building a schedule of items from a report that comes from a custodian. Recently the custodian changed its report format and my input sheet needs a small expansion. I need my code to be able to classify items by either a product code or a product description. My work-in-process code is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,'Product Codes'!A5:C20,3,FALSE),"Needs Review")
```

The formula below was the original that worked, however,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J5,'Product Codes'!A:B,2,FALSE),"Needs Review")
```

it does not cover the additional possibilities that can tie A, or now B, to C (classification type) with the introduction of the new reporting format. I now need a formula that can attribute either A or B (new "B" being the product descriptions) to the value shown in column C. Thank you for any help that can be provided!

Comment: have you tried something like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,'Product Codes'!A:C,3,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,'Product Codes'!B:C,2,FALSE),"Needs Review"))`? also the first code uses J4 while the second one uses J5...

Comment: @DirkReichel yes I know, but I was copying and pasting from excel and just used the cell underneath my work-in-process version. And also, I did try that but ended up with an error

Comment: theoretically it should run the vlookup for column A and output C... and if that fails, it does the same for column B (and output C)... however, the "product description" needs to match completely... using placeholder and stuff like that will not work :/

Comment: Still I would prefer INDEX/MATCH like `=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,IFERROR(MATCH(J4,A:A,0),MATCH(J4,B:B,0))),"Needs Review")`

Comment: @pnuts Still, there is no confirmation that this formula works...